# How to substract value from sum of values in Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I should substract given value from sum of values in Database!

**For example:** User "John" filled his account 2 time 100$ and 50$, Total in his account 150$
When he buy smth for 50$ We should substract from total money in his account!
and total money should be updated.

Here code to display total money in his account:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $sql = "SELECT sum(payment_amount) as 'payment' from payments 
    WHERE username= '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "' ";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo "" . $row['payment'] . "";
    ?>
```

**table: Payments**

```
  ID      username    payment_amount    Status  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   1   |  John       |     100     | Complete  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  John       |     50      | Complete  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   3   |  Alex       |     100     | Complete  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: I'd make 2 different tables for income and spend and select the sum of income minus sum of spends

Comment: why is this marked html when it is clearly a PHP question?

Comment: @LongChalk  because, This is logic behind the Website!

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: @tadman Could you alter code above with "Prepared statements" ?

Comment: [It's not hard to do yourself](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this like this when you are using balance.

The best way would be to create a new table like this.

**ID | userId | balance**

Then each payment, you only UPDATE DB using +$amount in the balance of user, and also, if he spent money, you just have to do the -$amount in your UPDATE.

Example:

***tbl_user***

**ID | name | email**

*1..alex...blabla@test.com*

---

***tbl_balance*** :

**ID | userId | balance**

*1....1.....100*

Comment: GOOD IDEA! Could you explain with query and code? With your recommended tables?

Comment: You should implement this as a [double entry ledger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping_system) with credits and debits recorded in pairs.

Comment: @tadman, you can just use another table for log for each transactions. But yea, good idea to got all your spent/entry.

Comment: Without that ledger you have no idea if these balances are correct or not. That's the important principle here. A number in a table can't be trusted. A series of transactions that sum up to a number can be audited and trusted.

Comment: Sorry but prepared statement can make it safe. This have nothing to do with security.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i can show you how i would do this, but it not 100% full but show you how it work.

```
/////PAYMENT PAGE/////

<?php 
/////Get the ID of user using his session username and after all you query your     user table WHERE username = $_SESSION["username"] and then you take the ID 
////And you save the id of user in a variable 
$getId = $row["id"];

/////Get the total balance of user right now using his id and save in variable
$getAmountNow = $row["balance"];
?>

<form action="myscript.php" method="get"> 
How much you want to pay <input type="text" name="amountPaid"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $getId; ?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $getAmountNow; ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
/////PAYMENT PAGE/////



/////myscript.php/////

$idUser = htmlspecialchars($_POST["id"]);
$amountNowUser = htmlspecialchars($_POST["balance"]);
$amountPaid = htmlspecialchars($_POST["amountPaid"]);

////If this is a spent
$newAmount = $amountNowUser - $amountPaid;

////If this is a buy
$newAmount = $amountNowUser + $amountPaid;

// prepare and bind$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_balance SET balance=? WHERE     idUser=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $newAmount, $idUser);
$stmt->execute();


/////myscript.php/////
```

Comment: A) Why are you adding two answers? B) What is `htmlspecialchars` doing here? That's not necessary nor appropriate for `bind_param` use. Aren't these numbers anyway? Bind with `i`.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your advices! How about my problem? Did you understand what I want? Could you explain how to do that? Or logic of doing it? Any ideas?

Comment: There's no easy way to explain this without knowing the fundamentals first. It's worth studying simple implementations of double-entry bookkeeping ledgers.

Comment: @tadman, for the first question, which is a real waste of time replying this, this is because i can't post answer, i'm a new user and don't have points to post as answer, also is that really serious about **htmlspecialchars** ?. This is to protected with XSS attack, while SQL prepared statement protect from SQL injection. Not the same thing at all.

_Edit: Yes true, using **i** bind param, but it should be an automatism._

Comment: You use `htmlspecialchars` if *and only if* displaying in an HTML context. It is not appropriate nor necessary to use when saving values to a database. Those values might appear in JSON, JavaScript, plain-text email, a URI, a lot of things that aren't HTML and require different escaping. If you pre-escape you must later unescape and re-escape correctly, which makes your application a real mess of confusion. Keep the data in your database raw, escape as necessary *if* necessary.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars();` is, in my opinion, the good way and simpler way to protect against XSS. Also, you can escape it in JSON or JS in any way, any manner you want when you fetch data. If you think that the HTML tags added in DB will mess your app, this is probably your app, the mess, for me.

Anyway, we all have our ways.

Comment: This is not a matter of opinion. You *should not* store your data escaped, it should be stored in as neutral a form as possible. You use escaping *only* when you're rendering it in a particular context, and then you use the escaping method appropriate for the context. Using `htmlspecialchars` protects from XSS *if and only if* it's used correctly, like when displaying data pulled from the database in an unescaped form. If you pre-escape you run the risk of double escaping, or having to unescape before re-escaping in the correct form. It's just not worth the trouble.

Comment: If you pre-escape then you're *assuming* all data in that table is safe. It may not be. Someone may find a way to insert raw data in there, bypassing your escaping, and then you have XSS problems. This is why you should **escape things when displaying them** so that these mistakes never happen.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, I've been answering PHP questions here for years. In that linked question the phrasing "document-creation-time" means precisely what I'm talking about: Escape *when rendering*, not *when saving to a database*.